# Trying to write a simple program to test dup(2) and open()

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that will create a file and print text to it. When I run the code, the file is made, but is corrupted and my function gets stuck.

```
void redirection(char* file) {
    // Create file
    int file_desc;
    mode_t mode = O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR;
    file_desc = open(file, mode);

    //Redirect output
    dup2(file_desc, 1);

    // Print and close file
    printf("hello");
    close(file_desc);
}
```

Comment: stuck like how? did you check `dup2`'s error code?

Comment: I have to control+c out of it! Whatever I type doesn't matter

Comment: Output to `stdout` (which is used by `printf`) is by default *line-buffered*, could that be an issue? What happens if you print a trailing newline in the string? Or manually call `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: Oh and to be able to really help you, we need to see a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Read the man page for open. You're calling it wrong.

Comment: " control+c out of it" what do you meant by this ? do you to ignore this signal while dup ?